# blink store data after change route

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, vuex

how can i avoid the data blink after update store data?
you can see the effect here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/178raL6AJiC4bpIOImnaTKh6Yf9GruTCz/view?usp=sharing

component:

```js
[...]
    mounted() {
        this.getIdeasFromBoard(this.$route.params.board_id);
    },
[...]
```

store:

```js
[...]
const actions = {
    getIdeasFromBoard({ commit, dispatch }, board_id) {
        apiClient
            .get('/ideas/' + board_id)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('success');
                commit("SET_IDEAS_BOARD", result.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error' + error);
                alert("You have failed to log in. Try again with another credentials.");
                dispatch('auth/logout', null,  { root: true });
                this.$router.push({ name: "public" });
            });
    },
[...]
```

i've searched some simple tutorial about consuming api with error handling, but didnt find it.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `IDEAS_BOARD` has the previous data until the new API call is completed. You would need to display a loader or a blank screen until the API call for the selected board is completed.

From actions, return a promise so that your component knows when is the call completed.

```
getIdeasFromBoard({ commit, dispatch }, board_id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      apiClient
        .get('/ideas/' + board_id)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('success');
            commit("SET_IDEAS_BOARD", result.data);
            resolve()
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error' + error);
            alert("You have failed to log in. Try again with another credentials.");
            dispatch('auth/logout', null,  { root: true });
            this.$router.push({ name: "public" });
            reject()
        });
  })
},
```

In your .vue component,

```
async mounted () {
  this.loading = true // some flag to display a loader instead of data
  await this.$store.dispatch()
  this.loading = false
}
```

There must be some other ways too like having this loading flag in the Vuex store. But it depends on you